# How to set the checkbox values when in an observableArray

Tags: jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

I have an observableArray of items that I mapped to a list of checkboxes.  They start off as all being unclicked.  But when a particular item is selected I want a set of checkboxes to become checked.

My Viewmodel:

```
       function ModelView(data) {
            var self = this;

            self.Items= ko.observableArray(data.Items);
            self.ItemOptions = ko.observableArray(data.ItemOptions ); 

            self.PreSelectOptions = function(item){
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.ItemOptions(), function (itemoption) {
                var selected = false;
                //Loop through the options the item has and preselect the checkboxes
                for (var i = 0; i < item.Option.length; i++) {
                    if (itemoption.ID == item.Option[x]) {
                        selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                itemoption.chosen = selected;//Check the checkbox
            }); 


       }
```

Html snippet:

```
       <ul data-bind="foreach: channels">
          <li>
              <input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: chosen' /><span data-bind="text: ChannelName"></span></li>
       </ul>
```

I have stepped through the code and itemoption.chosen is being set to true. Do I have to rebind the checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `chosen` is not an observable. The binding won't update automatically when bound to a non-observable.

You could make it an observable with code like this run after setting `self.ItemOptions`:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.ItemOptions(), function (itemoption) {
    itemoption.chosen = ko.observable(itemoption.chosen);
});
```

However, since self.ItemOptions is a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) of data.ItemOptions, the data object's item options will also be modified to use the observable. A better option might be to use the [`ko.mapping`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin:

```
self.ItemOptions = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.ItemOptions);
```

In either case, you'll need to change your syntax to reference `chosen` as an observable:

```
itemoption.chosen(selected); // Check the checkbox
```

Comment: Input type doesn't have a value so knockout won't really know what to check you may have to add value: ChannelName to the data-bind on the input

Comment: that answered my original question. But a second issue arrised:

Comment: @DanScan Did you miss some text? That sentence doesn't seem to have been finished. In any case, if the problem is separate, you might want to open a new question.

Comment: There was another issue that came up from this. Basically I was not able to easily link the checkboxs back to the model.  If I could find a descent tutorial on dynamic checkbox lists and the related model view would be awesome.